# Myelination of 1st Order Neurons in Spinal Cord Ascending Tracts

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

When a 1st order sensory neuron enters the Dorsal Column Ascending Pathway (i.e. Spinal Cord), does it get its myelination from Oligodendrocytes (as inside CNS) or it retains Schwann Cell myelination?

Comment: Is anyone at least up for a discussion?

Comment: Welcome. I think this is a great question. What have you found so far?

Comment: I haven't come across any text addressing this issue. But I think when the 1st order neuron enters the spinal cord it should retain Schwann Cell myelination (Considering Embryological Origin). But it contradicts with the statement that inside CNS oligodendrocytes myelinate Neurons. :(